# pip install --no-build-isolation returns no such option: --no-build-isolation

Tags: python, pip, centos, spacy-3

```
$ pip install --no-build-isolation --editable .

Usage:   
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --no-build-isolation
```

The above works on Ubuntu but not in CentOS.

Comment: Different versions of Python, no doubt.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: try`python3` and `pip3 install`

Comment: `--no-build-isolation` is a relatively recent pip feature, you probably need to upgrade pip. `pip install -u pip`.

Comment: [Do *not* run `pip` as root](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/do-not-run-pip-as-root)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In certain cases, projects (or redistributors) may have workflows that explicitly manage the build environment. For such workflows, build isolation can be problematic. If this is the case, pip provides a --no-build-isolation flag to disable build isolation. Users supplying this flag are responsible for ensuring the build environment is managed appropriately (including ensuring that all required build dependencies are installed).*

---

It is from **pip documentation v21.1.3,** check your pip version.

If you need upgrade, use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a different version of `pip` being used in Ubuntu than CentOS.
You can check the version via `python3 -m pip --version`

But since the comand says no such option you're version of `pip` is most likely too old.

To upgrade

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`